# buy signal in between two crossovers

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

## buy signal in between two crossovers

I have script for (two ema (8,20) and one sma (20) crossover buy, sell
strategy script) & one script for candle counting

"I want to combine it with candle counting script. So that it will
count candle from 1st crossover to 2nd and at the center of the
crossover it show long signal(buy signal)"

picture for better understanding https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7vRx.jpg

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='candle count', overlay=true,max_labels_count=500)

numBars = 1

t = time("D")

if t == t[1]
    numBars := nz(numBars[1]) + 1
    numBars
else
    numBars := 1
    numBars

label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(numBars), textcolor=color.blue, style=label.style_none)


//@version=3
    //study(title="ema crossover", overlay = true)
    strategy("EMA Crossover Strategy", overlay=true)
    
    src = input(close, title="Source")
    
    price = security(tickerid, period, src)
    ema1 = input(8, title="1st EMA Length")
    type1 = input("EMA", "1st EMA Type", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
    
    ema2 = input(20, title="2nd EMA Length")
    type2 = input("EMA", "2nd EMA Type", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
    
    sma3 = input(20, title="3rd MA Length")
    type3 = input("SMA", "3rd SMA type", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
    
    price1 = if (type1 == "EMA")
        ema(price, ema1)
    else
        sma(price, ema1)
    
    price2 = if (type2 == "EMA")
        ema(price, ema2)
    else
        sma(price, ema2)
    
    price3 = if (type3 == "SMA")
        sma(price, sma3)
    else
        ema(price, sma3)
    
    //plot(series=price, style=line,  title="Price", color=black, linewidth=1, transp=0)
    plot(series=price1, style=line,  title="1st EMA", color=red, linewidth=1, transp=0)
    plot(series=price2, style=line, title="2nd EMA", color=green, linewidth=1, transp=0)
    plot(series=price3, style=line, title="1st MA", color=black, linewidth=1, transp=0)
    
    
    longCondition = crossover(price1, price3) or crossover(price1, price2) or (price1 > price2) or (price2 > price3) or crossunder(price3, price2) or crossunder(price3, price1) or (price2 > price1) or (price1 > price1) 
    if (longCondition)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
    shortCondition = crossunder(price1, price2) and crossunder(price1, price3) or crossunder(price1, price2) and crossover(price1, price3)  
    if (shortCondition)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    
    plotchar(shortCondition, "shortCondition", "", location.abovebar, black, size = size.auto)
    plotchar(longCondition, "longCondition", "", location.belowbar, black, size = size.auto)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74053785/edit) your question because currently I am having trouble understanding what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ta.barssince** function [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}barssince](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dbarssince)

***Example:***

```
//@version=5

sma20 = ta.sma(close, 20)
ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema8  = ta.ema(close, 8)

condition = sma20 < ema20 and ema20 > ema8
since = ta.barssince(condition)
plot(since)
```